# Assistance with styling a dynamic asp:CheckBoxList using Bootstrap

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4, checkboxlist

I have an asp:CheckBoxList that is being populated with values from a DB. I'm using Bootstrap 4.3.1 as my framework. I'm trying to style my CheckBoxList using the default example:

```
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox my-1 mr-sm-2">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlInline">Remember my preference</label>
```

This is my code for my CheckBoxList:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CBLSymptoms" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellPadding="9"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

This is what I've tried, however the CheckBoxList disappears:

```
        <div class=" custom-control custom-checkbox my-1 mr-sm-2">
        <asp:CheckBoxList type="checkbox" CssClass="custom-control-input" ID="CBLSymptoms" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellPadding="9"></asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
```

If someone could kindly offer some input or advice on how I can achieve this, that would be excellent.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap classes won't work directly on the CheckBoxList control.

When I've needed to do this I created my own classes and applied them to a `div` element surrounding the CheckBoxList.

I also wrap in a `fieldset` for accessibility compliance.

CSS additions:

```
.checkbox.checkboxlist input[type="checkbox"]
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0.3rem;
    margin-left: -1.25rem;
}

.checkbox.checkboxlist label
{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

fieldset legend
{
    font-size: inherit;
}

fieldset .checkbox
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 1.25rem;
}
```

Markup:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Label for CheckBoxList</legend>
    <div class="checkbox checkboxlist">
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Flow">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Option one"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Option two"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Option three"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I've also got some classes for RadioButtonLists and horizontal forms on my [blog](http://blog.johnavis.com/blog/776/better-styling-and-accessibility-for-asp-net-controls-using-bootstrap-3/) which is where I copied much of this answer from.